# what exact image is the basis for the 圭?

Tags: meaning, etymology, glyph-origin, calligraphy

The Hanzi meaning for 圭 guī = (old) jade tablet (a ceremonial badge of rank)

I checked the images, not sure based on what jade tablet 圭 is drawn, can any one point to the correct image? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「圭」 does not come from a depiction of a tablet. That meaning of *jade tablet* is a semantic extension.

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| — | A | — |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 圭] | [乙](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)6776 [合集11006](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=11006&jgwfl=) |
| — | B | — |
| 商 玉璋 | [image: ⿹戈士] | 殷墟玉璋 |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 圭] | 師遽方彝 [集成9897](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9897&jgwfl=) |
| [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) 金 | [image: ⿹戈圭] | 旨於賜戈 [集成11310](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=11310&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state)) 石刻文 | [image: 圭] | 詛楚文 |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 圭] | 華山廟碑 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 圭] |  |

「圭」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[k]ʷˤe/**, *jade implement*) had two origins: A) the blade-head of a ceremonial jade [dagger-axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe) [「戈」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=127) (**/*kʷˤaj/**), and B) semantic [「士」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=41) (*bladed weapon* > *soldier*) with simultaneously semantic and phonetic 「戈」.

> For reference, [Shāng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)-era forms of 「戈」 inscribed with an emphasised blade-head:
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> 屯南2194</kbd>
> 　<kbd>商
> 金
> [image: 戈]
> 戈觶
> [集成6054](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6054&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Series A) doesn't survive in the modern writing system; for Series B), later on, 「士」 was doubled, and 「戈」 was omitted. The 「士」-shapes were eventually corrupted into [「土」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=40), forming 「圭」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [李學勤〈從兩條《花東》卜辭看殷禮〉](http://www.xianqin.org/xr_html/articles/shshyj/225.html)
- [陳劍《說殷墟甲骨文中的「玉戚」》](http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/902)
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [金文](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen)
- 王輝《殷墟玉璋朱書「⿹戈士」字解》
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 1):

If you google for images of 圭 you may find the designs vary a bit. The following is the shape given by dictionaries:

辞源 ▼

[image: 辞源]

汉语大字典 ▼

[image]